# Изучение Языка си

Tags: c, книги

Возможно мой вопрос не актуален, но всё равно хочу узнать мнение более опытных коллег. Я не так давно начал изучать язык си и конечно же начал с книги "Язык программирования C", в ней изложена вся суть языка, но как и любому другому новичку мне крайне не хватает практического опыта, и я хотел бы узнать мнение более опытных товарищей, какие книги следует прочитать, что бы набраться этого самого опыта?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Токо писать код. Начните проходить пазлы на codingames

Comment: Я думаю , что лучше придумать себе какой нибудь проект и кодить :)

Comment: Что бы набраться опыта нужна практика, полностью поддерживаю коллег выше)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ИМХО, но Я пришёл за всё время к тому, что главное понять суть языка, как он работает...

Но перед изучением следует знать английский в принципе.
С - практически красивый ассемблер.
Чтоб понять Си, нужно понять как работает железо, а для более сложных вещей и как работает ОС.

Т.О. следует логически вывод - Таненбаум, 2 книги: Архитектура компьютера + Операционные системы.

Ещё маленькими кусками смотри как выглядит код в ассемблере, можешшь тут: [онлайн компилятор в ассемблер](https://godbolt.org/)

И опять же, обязательна практика.
Если нет фантазии, иди по классике: Открываешь референс Стандартной библиатеки, смотришь функции, что принимает, что делает, реализуешь сам. Потом сравниваешь, смотришь, где криво сделал.

Answer (score 1):

Книга K&R - это классика, разумеется. Но она написана вовсе не для новичков. Это **справочник**, а вовсе не обучалка.

Если Вы **изучаете** язык С, то (IMHO) гораздо более подходящей книгой будет

> Дейтел П., Дейтел Х. "С для программистов с введением в С11" 
>   пер. с анг. А. Киселева. – М.: ДМК Пресс, 2014. – 544 с.: ил. ISBN
>   978-5-97060-073-3

Советы изучать (любой) язык программирования путём написания проекта с нуля напоминают мне советы не ходить на курсы по вождению, а сразу выруливать на Садовое кольцо :-)

Начинать изучение надо с написания не законченных проектов, а специально подобранных и организованных упражнений. Если вы считает себя гением, превзошедшим всех авторов учебников - можете сразу браться за проект. :-)