# С чего начать изучение языка C?

Tags: c

Хочу выучить язык С, но в интернете так много инфы, что даже не знаю с чего мне начать. Может быть, вы знаете какие-нибудь крутые книги, сайты и т.п. для изучения данного ЯП. И, пожалуйста, на русском языке. Только-только погружаюсь в изучение английского.

Comment: Читайте [K&R](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%B8_(%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0)) и делайте упражнения из нее.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576507/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d1%8b

Comment: @L.F.C., Второй вообще-то про с++, а вопрос о си.

Comment: @ヒミコ точно, убрал. В первом есть

Comment: си крутой язык. я начинал с head first c на русском. там есть описание как работать с указателями со списками, чего нет в K&R.  то есть в head first есть некое подобие объяснения как можно написать то и то. я сначала не понял сразу как со списками работать, но потом когда понадобилось я прочитал заново и уже получше понял. Желаю хорошо изучить этот замечательный язык.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вопрос повторяется регулярно.
И регулярно советую читать K&R :-)

Мой ответ по этому поводу можно посмотреть здесь:

[Изучение Языка си](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1056991/%d0%98%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%af%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b8/1057116#1057116)